# How to display a date field from an XPage in a pdf created with iText

Tags: xpages

After watching [David Leedy's video on creating pdfs from xpages](http://notesin9.com/index.php/2011/10/23/notesin9-ee-012-creating-pdfs-from-xpages/) using iText - I tried to create a pdf of a form in one of our XPage apps.  The form is basically a 2 column table with various data fields - name, address etc.  All of the text fields display perfectly but not the date fields.  Here is one example where I am trying to display the date of birth of the person (Person_dob) in cell 7 of my table.

```
var cell7 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph(currdoc.getItemValueString("Person_dob")));
```

This displays a blank in the table cell, not the value of the date field; I have tried changing the code and used both getItemValueDate and getItemValue instead of getItemValueString but this crashes the pdf before it even creates. No doubt I am missing something obvious but I just cannot see it.

Answer (score 1):

Use getItemValueDate() to get date as [Date](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_standard_date_r.html) object and convert it to a string in locale date format with [toLocaleDateString()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_standard_date_tolocaledatestring_r.html):

```js
var date = currdoc.getItemValueDate("Person_dob");
if (date != null) {
    var cell7 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph(date.toLocaleDateString()));
}
```

If you wish more control over the date format then you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in instead:

```js
var date = currdoc.getItemValueDate("Person_dob");
if (date != null) {
    var datePattern = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    var cell7 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph(datePattern.format(date)));
}
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is your friend!

Comment: Thanks for your help; I have tried both of your suggestions but in both cases I get an error message "Firefox can't find the file at http://xyz.nsf/pdf_test.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=C64E45A60AB1014A80257C0C00607BAB".

Comment: Does it really work without the date field and doesn't with just adding those lines from above? Have a try putting date code lines in a  `try {`...code...`} catch(e) {`...print error...`}` block and see what happens then.